# What's what with "Collect them all"

Tags: parts-of-speech

What is the modern grammarian's part-of-speech for **all** in

> Collect them all!

Comment: I believe *all* is a small clause and its POS is a (floating) quantifier. "Collect" is the verb and "them" is the object.

Comment: Why isn't **all** the object and **them** a modifier?

Comment: Because "them" is a pronoun, not a modifier unless it is in its informal, dialect form, which is not the case here.

Comment: Not sure I like them apples.

Comment: I told you. This is not the case here. This is not a dialect, informal situation.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo ...  Diamond has told you, and I trust you are now appropriately mollified.

Comment: What would be the missing predicate in this particular 'small clause'? And if we treat it as a small clause, wouldn't **all** then become analogous to **flat** in "Diamond pounded the nail *flat*"  -- a "predicative expression"?

Answer (score 2):

A [dictionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/all) shows that all can function as an adverb or a determiner (with a couple of minor uses). In this sentence, it is an adverb, roughly synonymous with "entirely" or "completely". It modifies the imperative verb "Collect".

Answer (score 1):

I don't know modern grammar, but The Teacher's Grammar of English suggests it's a *determiner* functioning as a quantifier. And the process of moving it to the final position is called a *quantifier-pronoun flip*.

> 1. Collect *all of them*
> 2. Collect *them all* <sup>Quantifier-pronoun flip</sup>

This quantifier-pronoun flip applies to a pronoun that is not a subject of the sentence.

Comment: CGEL might call it a determinative, perhaps.

Comment: A double equivocation?

Comment: Sorry @P.E.Dant, I don't understand you are trying to say. Do you mean answer is unclear? If so, I hope you can tell me what is unclear so I can fix it.

Comment: The comment is a comment upon your comment, not upon your answer. The conditional _might_ and the adverb _perhaps_ both express uncertainty. You must be familiar with the noun _equivocation!_

Comment: @P.E.Dant Yes, I'm familiar with that noun :). The comment is just as a  side note (and I'm very sure with that). I don't have a copy of CGEL but I heard that they consider "determiner" a function name not as a word class. And this function is realized by the so-called "determinative". (That is quite an arcane term to me.)

Comment: Are y'all sure about it applying only to a pronoun that is not a subject of the sentence?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo According to Ron Cowan (Author of TGE), native speakers sometimes apply it to a subject. But it usually results in an *awkward or questionably grammatical* sentence.

Answer (score 0):

> Collect [*them all*].

Here *them all* is a Compound-Pronoun.

In general, a compound word is formed by multiple lexemes, and hence individual lexemes can be classified into various known word-classes.

But here in *them all*, it's really hard to determine the word class of *all*. However, we have no problem identifying the Personal Pronoun - *them*. If pressed, I would call this *all* a Determinitive. But I'm not 100 percent sure about this.